# Are all singular functions of bounded variation?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, functions

Let $f$ be a function of bounded variation on $[a,b]$. Then there exist a unique pair (up to adding a constant) of absolute continuous function $g$ and singular function $h$ (i.e., $h'=0$ a.e.) such that $f=g+h$. Since $h=f-g$, $f,g$ are both of bounded variation, $h$ is of bounded variation.

Are all singular functions of bounded variation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true.

For example, define $f(x)=0$ if $x$ is rational, and $1$ otherwise. Then $f$ is obviously singular (it's constant a.e.), but $f$ is not of bounded variation on any interval (easy to prove).

Comment: $f$ is not differentiable at each point. I want to modify: $f(x)=0$ for $x$ irrational, $f(m/n)=1/n$ for irreducible $m/n$.